# DropdownSearch bajo un FutureBuilder con items de un modelo

Tags: flutter, dart

El siguiente codigo me arroja este error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
he intentado muchas cosas distintas pero no se lo que debo cambiar para que me funcione correctamente. cualquier ayuda se agradece.

Lo que intento hacer a continuacion es obtener todo los tipos de items para listarlos en el dropdownsearch y en base a eso crear un nuevo item, pero tengo problemas con la parte de la propiedad 'items' del widget dropdownsearch, al parecer es por el tipo de dato que obtiene desde el provider pero no se como solucionarlo

```
 Widget dropdownsearch() {
   return FutureBuilder(
     future: tipoItemServicioProvider.getTipoItemsActivos(),
     builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
       if (snapshot.hasData) {
         print(snapshot.data);
         return DropdownSearch<dynamic>(
           mode: Mode.MENU,
           showSearchBox: true,
           showClearButton: true,
           showSelectedItems: true,
           itemAsString: (item) => item!['nombre'],
           items: snapshot.data,
           compareFn: (item, selectedItem) =>
               item!['nombre'] == selectedItem!['nombre'],
           label: "Tipo de Item",
           hint: "Tipo de Item (*)",
           onChanged: (seleccionado) {
             seleccionado;
             print(seleccionado!['id']);
           },
           validator: (value) => value == null ? 'campo requerido' : null,
           selectedItem: null,
         );
       } else {
         return Container();
       }
     },
   );
 }
```

Este es el provider

```
  Future<List<TipoItemServicio>> getTipoItemsActivos() async {
    var url = Uri.parse(getUrl() + 'tipo-item-servicio/activos');
    var respuesta = await http.get(url, headers: getHeaders());
    // print(url);
    if (respuesta.statusCode == 201) {
      var decodedData = json.decode(respuesta.body);
      final tipoItemServicio =
          TipoItemServicios.fromJsonList(decodedData['data']);
      // print(decodedData['data']);
      tipoItemServicioSink(tipoItemServicio.items);
      return tipoItemServicio.items;
    } else {
      tipoItemServicioSink([]);
      return [];
    }
  }
```

Este es el modelo

```
class TipoItemServicio {
  int? id;
  String? nombre;
  int? estado;
  String? created_at;
  String? updated_at;

  TipoItemServicio(
      {this.id, this.nombre, this.estado, this.created_at, this.updated_at});

  TipoItemServicio.fromJsonMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    nombre = json['nombre'];
    estado = json['estado'];
    created_at = json['created_at'];
    updated_at = json['updated_at'];
  }
}

class TipoItemServicios {
  List<TipoItemServicio> items = [];

  TipoItemServicios();

  TipoItemServicios.fromJsonList(List<dynamic> jsonList) {
    if (jsonList.isEmpty) return;
    for (var item in jsonList) {
      final tipo_item_servicio = TipoItemServicio.fromJsonMap(item);
      items.add(tipo_item_servicio);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El `Future` usa este método para obtener datos:

```dart
 future: tipoItemServicioProvider.getTipoItemsActivos(),
```

Ese método retorna elementos del tipo `TipoItemServicio`.

En de tu `DropdownSearch` estás usando `dynamic` como tipo de dato, podrías usar el tipo que retornas, el cual es `TipoItemServicio`.

Luego ya podrías cambiar la forma como extraes y muestras datos, en lugar de :

```dart
itemAsString: (item) => item!['nombre'],
           compareFn: (item, selectedItem) =>
               item!['nombre'] == selectedItem!['nombre'],
           onChanged: (seleccionado) {
             seleccionado;
             print(seleccionado!['id']);
           },
```

Podría ser:

````dart
itemAsString: (item) => item!.nombre,
           compareFn: (item, selectedItem) =>
               item!.nombre == selectedItem!.nombre,
           onChanged: (seleccionado) {
             seleccionado;
             print(seleccionado!.id);
           },
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

espero que esta respuesta te ayude, tienes que mapear la lista que te retorna la función, primero dentro del if declara una variable y asignale el valor de `snapshot.data`:

```
if(snapshot.hasData){
   final list = snapshot.data;
   //código restante
  }
```

Después de esto, vas a mapear tu lista:

```
 items: lista!.map((item) {
     return item.nombreCategoria.
            toString();
 }).toList());
```

Con eso ya deberías poder visualizar los items que hay